# How to calculate Time Complexity in the Big O notation for following array double lookup

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What will be time complexity of the following algorithm ?? Can some one help

```
public class Util
{

    public static int GetDistance(int[] array)
    {
        //Find the max seperation of two same numbers inside an array for example 
        // {1,2,4,1,5,9,0,4,15,1,2} should return 9 ( position of '1' at 9th and 0th location)

        int N = array.Length;
        int maxDistance=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (N-1); j > i; j--) 
             {
                 if (array[j]==array[i])   
                    if(maxDistance < (j-i))
                        maxDistance = j- i;
             }//End of inner for

        }//End of for
        System.Console.WriteLine("maxDistance " + maxDistance);
        return maxDistance ;
    } //End of Function

} //End of Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You look at the inner loop (the operation inside the inner loop take constant time). The inner loop is executed exactly `N-1-i` times.

Then the outer loop is executed exactly `N` times, with increasing values of `i`. The total workload involves

```
(N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 1
```

executions of the inner body. This sum is a triangular number and it is not a big deal to show that it equals

```
(N-1).N / 2
```

This is O(N²).

Comment: Does it mean that time complexity representation  of O(N²) is same as O((N²-N)/2) ?
Then

Comment: Of course. For large N, N is neglectible compared to N².

Answer (score 0):

You have two for loop which iterate N times (the second is also impact by the number N, meaning N bigger, the iteration number bigger).

Inside the loop, the operation is O(1)
So totally you have O(1) * O(N^2) = O(N^2)

Comment: Does it mean that time complexity representation  of O(N²) is same as O((N²-N)/2) ?
this implies that big-O notation is not a good comparison parameter as the following loops will also has same time complexity but 50% more cycle
<code>for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (N-1); j >=0; j--)  // reverse iterating complete array
             {
                 if (array[j]==array[i])   
                    if(maxDistance < (j-i))
                        maxDistance = j- i;
             }//End of inner for

        }//End of for

</code>

Comment: Big-O is good comparison for what is it supposed for, i.e. general performance of algorithm, especially toward large N. If you are reasoning about real world performance of some code, you must **profile** it. There may be easily cases where O(N^2) outperforms O(N), if the input N is not large enough for the real input data and when the complexity of that O(N) code is way beyond the price of N^2 in first code. For example when you are using only about 1e6 of integers, with random insert and remove in C++, `vector<int>` is faster (O(N^2)) than double linked list (O(N)) (because of cache misses).

Comment: the inner loop does not iterate N times every time

Comment: The inner loop does not iterate N times every time. I agree with that, but the thing is it's not a constant time iteration, and it is always impact by N. If you have a bigger N, the inside loop iteration is always bigger. In the big-O annotation, O(kN) = O(N), if k is constant. So the inner loop is O(N).